# Stuck on changing jquery code to a jquery function. (Checkes if multiple checkboxes checked)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox

I'm trying to convert this code, which is working on its own but its stupid to copy paste the same thing over and over again (here's the [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K57dW/)).

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
    if ( $('#in-name-01').is(':checked') && $('#in-name-02').is(':checked') ) {

        $('#name-313').css("display","block");
        $('#name-314').css("display","block");
        $('#name-315').css("display","block");
        $('#name-316').css("display","block");
        $('#name-317').css("display","block");
return;                                                                                 
      } else {

        $('#name-313').removeAttr("style");
        $('#name-314').removeAttr("style");
        $('#name-315').removeAttr("style");
        $('#name-316').removeAttr("style");
        $('#name-317').removeAttr("style");

    }});
```

I've written something like this:

```
function showByArray(name, idArray){
    for(var i=0; i<idArray.length; i++){
        jQuery('#'+name+'-'+idArray[i]).show();
    }
}

function hideByArray(name, idArray){
    for(var i=0; i<idArray.length; i++){
        jQuery('#'+name+'-'+idArray[i]).hide();
    }
}

function namechecker(id,otherId, name, idArray){
    if (jQuery('#'+id).is(':checked') && jQuery('#'+otherId).is(':checked')) 
    {
        showByArray(name,idArray);                                  
        return;
    }else{
        hideByArray(name,idArray);
    }
}


namechecker('in-name-01', 'in-name-02', 'name', [313,314, 315,316,317]);
```

`showByArray` and `hidebyArray` are working (I'm using for other parts of the code with single checkboxes) but I don't think `namechecker` does. Here is the this version's Jfiddle

Comment: your second fiddle does not include jquery, with jquery and checked boxes http://jsfiddle.net/epudL/2/ seems to work

Comment: Ups sorry, (i've included in the updated post again. Thanks for heads up)

Comment: the code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/epudL/5/

Comment: Thats odd! it does?! Ill implement it on the main body to see if it does while included in my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Working fine. You need to encapsulate the `namechecker` function in the checkbox click function.

Comment: I was already using it inside my main project but i think i forgot to transfer it here. The code does work in the jfiddle but something is interfering it in the main file it seems.

Thanks alot for confirming it.

Comment: It seems i got id's overlaping on functions. How can i use these functions altough they overlap? http://jsfiddle.net/epudL/15/
(checkbox1 and 2 should create the same result of checkbox2 and checkbox3)